# Oracle APEX values do not load on the form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

From my APEX page I am opening a pop up page and trying to load it with data from the database. To do so, I used 
Pre-Rendering After Header Process. Process type is set to PL/SQL code:

```
BEGIN
  IF :P3_RECORD_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
     select TYPE_ID, RECORD_TEXT
     INTO :P3_TYPE_ID, :P3_RECORD_TEXT
     from TABLE1
     where RECORD_ID = :P3_RECORD_ID;
  END IF;
END;
```

On the pop up page I have a dropdown (P3_TYPE_ID) which is filled from the LOV and a text field (P3_RECORD_TEXT).
The values show up in the session state but not in the dropdown or a text field. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong...

I also tried Automated Row Fetch but that did not load any values into fields either, just into session state

Comment: That behavior is expected if on the section SOURCE the "type" field is "null" and "used" is "Always, replacing any existing value in session state". But, if this process is fast, the solution of Littlefoot is better.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using **default value** for those items? It would be a "PL/SQL Function Body" and look like this (for `P3_TYPE_ID`):

```
declare
  l_type_id table1.type_id%type;
begin
  select max(type_id)
  into l_type_id
  from table1
  where record_id = :P3_RECORD_ID;

  return l_type_id;
end;
```

I used `MAX` function to avoid possible `NO_DATA_FOUND` and `TOO_MANY_ROWS` errors. Handle them in `EXCEPTION` section, if necessary.

Similarly, populate `P3_RECORD_TEXT`.

Comment: could you explain how that is going to help?

Comment: Did you try it (and it didn't work), or are you just being curious?

Comment: what exactly does it do?

Comment: You are passing RECORD_ID value to the page P3 and - based on its value - populate TYPE_ID and RECORD_TEXT items. Default item value is used to set item's value if it doesn't exist. As you want to fetch those values from the database (based on RECORD_ID), those SELECT statements (actually, functions) set those values. I don't know what you plan to do with them once you fetch them.

Comment: I see (I thought that you just want to *display* those values). In that case, what you tried (i.e. automatic row processing) is the right way. I'd suggest you not to do it yourself - the simplest way is to create a report + form (usually an interactive report which calls a form that lets you edit database values). Let the wizard create everything; then delete the IR page (unless you need it), and - on your current "master" page (the one that calls Page 3) - create a link which will populate record ID. Automatic row processing should do the rest.